# What is the algebraic structure of $\Bbb Q_p/\Bbb Z_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, topological-groups, p-adic-number-theory

I am curious about the algebraic structure of $\Bbb Q_p/\Bbb Z_p$.

Is there any result in this direction?

Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbb Q_p$ is a field, isn't it?

Comment: @FredrikMeyer Yes, it is a field, but the question is perhaps about the additive structure of the quotient $\Bbb Q_p/\Bbb Z_p,$ i.e. the quotient of two additive abelian groups.

Comment: @awllower Thank you for explaining.

Comment: Read page four here: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/characterQ.pdf That quotient group is isomorphic with the p-power subgroup of the rather well known $\;\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z\;$

Comment: Or: you may think of it as the $p$-power torsion subgroup of the circle group.